# Converting a polar integral to spherical

Tags: multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\sqrt{2}}\int_r^{\sqrt{4-r^2}}\mathrm{d}z \, r \, \mathrm{d}r \, \mathrm{d}\theta$$

So in spherical this would become: $$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\pi/4}\int_0^2 \rho^2\sin\phi \, \mathrm{d} \rho \, \mathrm{d}\phi \, \mathrm{d}\theta,$$ correct?

Comment: Yes it is correct.

Comment: @Mhenni Benghorbal Thank you!